# 2 column List with cross hair border using bootstrap or flexbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

How to create a a 3 or 4 column unordered list with 3 rows with cross hair border (no borders on outside only inside) . I would like to use CSS3, Bootstrap/Flexbox to do this with html and css only. kindly view image for final result. thanks so much, im learning to code and trying to build this using above tools only.

4 column 3 row layout with inside border:

[image: 4column 3 row layout with inside border]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 2em;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row > ul > li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  /*flex: 1;*/
}
.row > ul > li {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.row > ul > li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.row:last-child ul > li {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="row">
    <ul class="row">
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <ul class="row">
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <ul class="row">
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/accelrys1.png" alt="">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to occupy the entire page with just uncomment the line `flex: 1` in `.row > div` class.

Comment: Good use of `>` selector!

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij Thank you!

Comment: thanks, but i need to use a <ul> instead of so many divs...

Comment: I've edited the code please check it.

Comment: Thank you, almost there, order does not matter in how the images wrap in the row, hence can we use one UL and all images within the UL. (one UL only)

Comment: @Ricky-U you can use single `ul`, but you can not display them in 4 column 3 row layout.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: #BDBDBD;
    padding: 0;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.item {
    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 25%;
    background: white;
}

div.item:nth-child(1){
    margin-right: 1px;
}

div.item:nth-child(2){
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

div.item:nth-child(3){
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

div.row:nth-child(1){
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

div.row:nth-child(3){
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can this be done using a unordered-list instead of many divs?

Comment: Yes you can, just use ul instead of row and container, and rest will be li. Only that you may need to overwrite display of li.